# How to handle a lecture course remotely?

Tags: professorship, lecturer, lecture-notes

I tried to contact my classmates to ask for their notes, I email 5 of them and none of them have replied back. 
I have a high GPA and this course is my last course at the university, I really want to get a perfect mark. 
I was wondering if you could please tell me how can I study this course remotely?
How should I approach the instructor? It would be ok if one classmate could record the class voice weekly for me, but no one would do this for me.

Comment: Do you mean *commute* between cities?

Comment: I live in another city now due to my research.

Comment: Did you consider buying and learning from a book? Maybe your instructor can recommend one?

Comment: His assignments are different than the recommended textbook, he is copying another prof assignments(from a prof at a university at USA)

Comment: I assume you have the same access to assignments that those attending do. The recommended textbook should also be a help, actually, if it is well written and has its own exercises for you to get the necessary practice. A good way to learn is to do more exercises than the minimum assigned.

Comment: Have you tried the textbook (or whatever other resources) used (or written) by the American prof who wrote the assignments?

Answer (score 7):

Talk to the instructor, ask them for advice.

Ideally you would have done this before the semester started knowing that you would have this arrangement, but at least the instructor was made aware ahead of time through your supervisor.

They are unlikely to be able to offer support that takes a lot of additional effort on their part because this special arrangement is due to your needs (placing the burden on you), but they may be able to facilitate note sharing, suggest an appropriate additional text, or possibly share some additional lecture notes or outlines of their own.

Comment: I took this course during add and drop in the very last minute. As I am away I have not had any in-person conversation with the instructor, all my communications were through emails. My advisor talked to him and told him that I can not attend regular sessions, the only difficult part for me are the assignments. project and final  are OK.

Comment: @programmer None of that changes my answer.

Comment: Bryan Krause, he already offered two textbooks but none of them are appropriate, I would ask for additional textbooks. But even I have a problem submitting my assignments, to submit them I would have to log in with my university internet id.

Comment: @programmer Talk to your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a long-shot possibility. Some universities have a way to record or even live-stream lectures. If you haven't explored this, you might see if it can be done. There might be a special office, audio-visual, or such. Even audio might be a help to you if you also have lecture slides.

Failing that, the professor might be able to record audio and send it to you or upload it to a web page. The quality would likely be better if there are professionals involved, of course.